# Building Editor in Gazebo 4.1 doesn't offer floorplan import

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to model a complex floorplan of a very large indoor environment.  I have accurate floorplan models, and would like to import them into the building editor in order to accurately place walls and such.  Unfortunately, the Import button doesn't show up at all for me in Gazebo.  I've installed packages from osrf, ros packages, and done a compile from source, and none of those options have solved the problem.  What am I missing here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7763/building-editor-in-gazebo-4.1-doesn%27t-offer-floorplan-import/) by [bradleypowers](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1067/bradleypowers/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Importing a floorplan image has been added in [pull request 1214](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/1214/building-editor-import-background-image) to the gazebo default branch and will be released in gazebo 5.0. Until gazebo 5.0 is released, you must [build from source](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_from_source&cat=install) to use this feature.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bradleypowers](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1067/bradleypowers/) on 2014-12-30**:
Excellent, thank you!